# Can I Use a Mains to USB charger cable to power a SATA cable?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, usb, sata, nas

I want to connect a 500GB hard drive to my Network storage via the USB on the back of my router... However, I only have one USB on my router and I have a USB to SATA cable which needs two, due to the large amount of power it uses. Now, this got me thinking... will using a standard, say 1A USB wall plug be sufficient to plug into one of the two cables coming from my USB to SATA converter, will this be a) usable, and b) safe?

Comment: The safest thing to do is to buy a powered USB hub, and attach your storage drive to the hub with the provided USB Y-Cable.

Comment: What is a “mains”?

Comment: @Ramhound Presumably he means a USB charger cable adapter that plugs into a main electrical socket.

Comment: @DavidPostill Author should clarify

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity

Comment: I dont see how 5v USB is going give you the 12v most drives need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work.

Standard USB bus power is just 0.5A @ 5V, so 2.5W. In my experience, anything that has an extra USB Type-A connector for power is just looking for that extra 2.5W it can expect from any random USB port.

Typical USB Type-A wall chargers can provide even more amperage for devices that can draw it. They typically do at least a full 1A @ 5V for 5W (this is what Apple popularized with early iPod/iPhone chargers), and some do as high as 2.4A @ 5V for 12W.